# Unable to save a hashmap object into a file in android

Tags: android, serialization, hashmap, lazy-loading, drawable

I'm downloading lot of images from Internet and storing into a `hashmap` and showing in a `ListView`. I want to cache the images. For that, I am storing the `Hashmap` object into a file inside `onDestroy()` of my activity and getting back the object inside `oncreate()`.

```
Map<String, Drawable> hashmap; //storing the urls of images and downloaded image `Drawables` into this map
```

Inside `onCreate()`:

```
       File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/image_cache.ser");
        if(f.exists()){ 
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            hashmap = (HashMap<String, Drawable>)ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            Here creating a custom adapter and showing the hashmap drawable images in a listview 
          }
```

Inside onDestroy()

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/image_cache.ser");

    try {
        if(hashmap != null && hashmap.size() >= 1){

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
            oos.writeObject(hashmap);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        f.delete();
    }

}
```

Problem : Getting this exception:

`java.io.NotSerializableException android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable inside ondestoy().`

Why the `hashmap` `object` is not getting serialized ? Where i am going wrong. Could you please put me in a correct way if I'm wrong to cache images?

Comment: java.io.NotSerializableException  .... java.io.NotSerializableException .... java.io.NotSerializableException

Answer (score 0):

you can not write your hashmap because the class `Drawable` is not `Serializable`

`Drawable` does not implement `Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

It just won't work this way. The errors says, that you are trying to serialize a Drawable, which is not implemented, since there are factories to do so in different ways. There is no simple solution with this hashmap.